# Tools similar to nodemon, for perl

Tags: macos, perl

Is there something like `nodemon`, that monitors file changes and restarts a perl script?

My perl script is just a while loop.

I tried to google for it, but results are either about `mod_perl` or irrelevant.

Any ideas?

I'm using Mac OS

Comment: Is [File::Monitor](http://metacpan.org/module/File::Monitor)
the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: It depends very stong on which operating system you are using.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to restart the program when the program itself changes?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a tool like nodemon for Perl, unless there's one for generically restarting any program when it changes.  Here's one I knocked together.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use File::Monitor;
use Child qw(child);

sub start_program {
    my $program = shift;

    return child {
        exec $^X, $program, @ARGV;
    };
}

sub restart_program {
    my($program, $child) = @_;

    $child->kill("TERM");

    return start_program($program);
}

sub monitor_program {
    my $program = shift;

    my $monitor = File::Monitor->new;

    my $child = start_program($program);

    say "PID: ".$child->pid;

    $monitor->watch($program, sub {
        $child = restart_program($program, $child);
    });

    while(1) {
        sleep 1;
        $monitor->scan;
    }
}

monitor_program(shift);
```

This could be made more efficient by replacing [File::Monitor](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Monitor) with something hooking into the OS X filesystem event service.